# JavaScript objects property to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```js
const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Forrest Gump',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Get Out',
  },
};
```

Then I want an array with only the property id. To do so I've tried something like:

```js
const moviesArray = Object.values(movies);
const idArray = moviesArray.map(movie => Object.values(movie)[0]);
console.log(idArray);
```

It prints `idArray` properly but my question is if am I missing a method to solve this problem.

Comment: Object.keys(movies)

Comment: `Object.values(movies).map(movie => movie.id)`

Comment: is there any reason to store the objects in an object with numbers as properties? Storing it in array would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `id` property directly:

```js
const
    movies = { 1: { id: 1, name: 'Planet Earth' }, 2: { id: 2, name: 'Selma' }, 3: { id: 3, name: 'Million Dollar Baby' }, 4: { id: 4, name: 'Forrest Gump' }, 5: { id: 5, name: 'Get Out' } },
    moviesArray = Object.values(movies),
    idArray = moviesArray.map(movie => movie.id);

console.log(idArray);
```

Comment: Yes I forgot I can simply access to 'movie.id', but is there any method to do this directly instead of values and map?

Comment: @Jquino, actually you nee the two steps to access unknown properties in an array and mapping for the property.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Forrest Gump',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Get Out',
  },
};

const moviesArray = Object.values(movies);
const idArray = moviesArray.map(movie => movie.id);
console.log(idArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I this case, I'd be more inclined to use `movie => movie.id` as your mapper function, rather than `movie => Object.values(movie)[0]`.

The issue with your current function is that it assumes `id` will always happen to be the first property in the Array returned by `Object.values`. That happens to be true with your current function as written, but I'm not sure you can necessarily guarantee that in the general case. Directly referencing `movie.id`works even if the properties come in a different order. It should also be a bit faster, since you don't have to convert eaxh individual object to an Array each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there wasn't a need for using `Object.values` in the `map` part here. It would have been same without it:

```js
const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Forrest Gump',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Get Out',
  },
};
const moviesArray = Object.values(movies);
    const idArray = moviesArray.map(movie => movie);
    console.log(moviesArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can go with more core version.
In my solution the loop will be running only once.

```js
const movies = {
  1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Planet Earth',
  },
  2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Selma',
  },
  3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Million Dollar Baby',
  },
  4: {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Forrest Gump',
  },
  5: {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Get Out',
  },
};


const idArray = [];
for (let i in movies) {
 idArray.push(movies[i].id);
}

console.log(idArray);
```